# Cloud tasks stops sending requests after a certain number of requests to a cloud run app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I have a cloud task queue where i place 2500 orders to be processed every 5 minutes. The task sends the requests to a cloud run app in flask with gunicorn, the average response time of the cloud run is 2 seconds (it needs to make a request to external providers, cannot optimize much there).

The system responds well for some time, but after some unknown conditions the cloud tasks system stops sending requests at the specified rate (80 max concurrency, add 20 per second), and only dispatches 1 task per second aproximately, it doesn't matter if i deploy a new revision or pause the queue, it restarts again after many minutes.

In the docs i found that it is possible that cloud tasks reduces the dispatch rate if there are 503 errors (i never return that in my app) or if there are too many failures, but the failure rate is something like 8% and has only 1 retry.

I tried lots of configurations but i cannot find the reason why cloud tasks and cloud run are getting stuck, if i manually run the tasks they execute, if i call my app with postman it responds OK. I have the same app deployed in app engine and it works perfectly, the cloud task always send the same number of requests.

How can i debug to find the problem? Maybe it's another layer between cloud run and cloud tasks? Couldn't find any clue around the docs.

UPDATE:
My cloud run memory and cpu usage is low i also played with concurrent requests and it didn't matter.

However i think i've found the reason, my endpoint returns 500 if the provider responds with any error, so i can retry soon, in a few cases i might have a considerable error rate, and cloud tasks seems to lower dispatch rate to avoid errors. But now i'm wondering, why this does't happen with app engine and how can i turn that property off, i want my dispatch rate to be the one i specified i don't want gcp to throttle my services

Comment: Start with monitoring, metrics, and logs. What do they show before the event horizon? If I had to guess, I would first review the instance size, CPU utilization, and memory usage. They will probably indicate selecting a larger Cloud Run instance size or a reduction of concurrent requests per container. Edit your post with the Cloud Run configuration and details from monitoring, metrics, and logging.

Comment: i think i've found the reason, my endpoint returns 500 if the provider responds with any error, so i can retry soon, in a few cases i might have a considerable error rate, and cloud tasks seems to lower dispatch rate to avoid errors. 
But now i'm wondering, why this does't happen with app engine and how can i turn that property off, i want my dispatch rate to be the one i specified i don't want gcp to throttle my services.

Comment: @Gammel did you ever figure out how to avoid HTTP Cloud Tasks from throttling when receiving HTTP 500 responses? Or did you end up using a different approach?